# Postgresql not connecting to android studio via java

Tags: java, android, sql, postgresql, gradle

I'm new to java and sql, I'm trying to connect to the postgresql program but I get an error and nothing happens. I can't figure out what's wrong

```
Unused import statement
Class 'ConnectPG' is never used
Method 'connectBD()' is never used
Method 'disconnection(java.sql.Connection)' is never used
```

I have two java class files, one "ConnectPG" I want to connect to postgresql through it, and the file "insertRecordExample" through it I try to enter values into the table. But nothing works. When I start debugging SEPARATELY on the "insertRecordExample" file, the program gives an error:

"
16:53:59: Executing ':app:InsertRecordExample.main()'...
enter code here`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Blockquote

- Where:
  Initialization script 'C:\Users\fff\AppData\Local\Temp\InsertRecordExample_main__.gradle' line: 41
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
  Could not create task ':app:InsertRecordExample.main()'.
  SourceSet with name 'main' not found.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 110ms
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
16:54:00: Execution finished ':app:InsertRecordExample.main()'.
"

Java File ConnectPG:

```
package com.example.a112new;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ConnectPG {
Connection connect=null;
public Connection connectBD(){
        try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        // localhost
connect=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/112", "postgresql",  "430890");
                }catch (Exception er) {
        System.err.println(er.getMessage());
}
   return connect;

}
//
protected void disconnection(Connection con)throws Exception {
    con.close();
}
}
```

Java File InsertRecordExample:

```
     package com.example.a112new;
    //package net.javaguides.postgresql.tutorial;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * Insert PrepareStatement JDBC Example
 *
 * @author Ramesh Fadatare
 *
 */
public class InsertRecordExample {
//localhost
private final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/112";
private final String user = "postgres";
//    root
private final String password = "111111";

private static final String INSERT_USERS_SQL = "INSERT INTO users" +
        "  (user_id, lastname, firstname, patronymic, birth,phone,email,password) VALUES             
" +
        " (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

public static void main(String[] argv) throws SQLException {
    InsertRecordExample createTableExample = new InsertRecordExample();
    createTableExample.insertRecord();
}

public void insertRecord() throws SQLException {
    System.out.println(INSERT_USERS_SQL);
    // Step 1: Establishing a Connection
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

         // Step 2:Create a statement using connection object
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_USERS_SQL)) {
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "FFFF");
        preparedStatement.setString(3, "FFFF");
        preparedStatement.setString(4, "FFFFF");
        preparedStatement.setString(5, "2005-01-12");
        preparedStatement.setString(6, "+79888888888");
        preparedStatement.setString(7, "11111@gmail.com");
        preparedStatement.setString(8, "1234567");

        System.out.println(preparedStatement);
        // Step 3: Execute the query or update query
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        // print SQL exception information
        printSQLException(e);
    }

    // Step 4: try-with-resource statement will auto close the connection.
}

public static void printSQLException(SQLException ex) {
    for (Throwable e: ex) {
        if (e instanceof SQLException) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.err.println("SQLState: " + ((SQLException) e).getSQLState());
            System.err.println("Error Code: " + ((SQLException) e).getErrorCode());
            System.err.println("Message: " + e.getMessage());
            Throwable t = ex.getCause();
            while (t != null) {
                System.out.println("Cause: " + t);
                t = t.getCause();
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.
I tried to identify the problem through logcat "--warning-mode=all" But it's no use, it doesn't give any errors at all. Gives errors only InsertRecordExample when I run it ONE! If I run the entire program, there are no errors as such, only those that I described above. I apologize in advance for my English.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android emulator to test your app then you shouldn't use 127.0.0.1 in your connection string, but 10.0.2.2, because if you are running both your server and your emulator on the same machine the 127.0.0.1 will refer to the emulator itself.

But generally JDBC doesn't work well at all when it comes to Android, so it may not be your mistake, but simply that JDBC doesn't work correctly. The best way of connecting to your database is using web services.